# Update the object value using checkbox and submit button

Tags: jquery, html

Hello I'm working on a mini project that will add objects to an array and display it to a table in html.

I have radio button for each row/object. If checkbox is selected I wanted to update a value of my key.

```
<div class="container">
    <input id="list-input" />
    <select id="select-status">
        <option value="on-going">on-going</option>
        <option value="completed">completed</option>
    </select>
    <button id="add">Add To List</button>
    <button id="update">Mark as Complete</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Your List</h1>

    <div>
        <table id="mylist">
            <thead>
                <th>ID Number</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <button id="clear">clear</button>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/8jz1v3u7/)

I wanted to mark the status sa complete both in my array and in my html. 
Would really appreciate help on the above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code goes through each row, inspects its checkbox, and then updates the table and array if checked.

```
$('#update').on('click', function() {
  var rows = $("#mylist tbody tr");

  $.each(rows, function(i, row) {
      if( $(this).find('td').eq(3).find("input").is(":checked") ) {
          $(this).find('td').eq(2).text("complete");
          tasks[i].status = "complete";              
      }
  });

  // This console.table is here so you can see that the array is updated.
  // You can remove it when you are satisfied this works.
  console.table(tasks);  

});
```